About the connection between distance in Hilbert space and fidelity
I have the feeling that there is a direct relationship between the distance in Hilbert space and the fidelity (similarity) between quantum states.

short version : the distance between two quantum states and is defined as the norm of their difference vector:
d(ψ,ϕ)=∥ψ−ϕ∥=⟨ψ−ϕ∣ψ−ϕ⟩​

Now, as far as I undertstand, this norm/ distance in Hilbert space is a measure of how different two quantum states are, with fidelity providing a direct way to quantify their similarity.Higher fidelity thus indicates greater similarity between states, resulting in a smaller distance ; while lower fidelity (typically, with orthogonal states) indicates greater dissimilarity, resulting in a larger distance.
Would you agree with that ?

Long version -- or an attempt to make a rigorous connection between the distance in Hilbert space and the notion of fidelity. At least, for pure states.

Let's take to pure states $$(\psi) and (\phi)$$
The fidelity is given by the absolute value of the inner product:
$$
 F(\psi, \phi) = |\langle \psi | \phi \rangle|
 $$
Now, the distance between the states is the norm of their difference:
$$
 d(\psi, \phi) = \|\psi - \phi\| = \sqrt{\langle \psi - \phi | \psi - \phi \rangle}
 $$
The, using the properties of inner products, we can expand the norm:
$$
 \|\psi - \phi\|^2 = \langle \psi - \phi | \psi - \phi \rangle = \langle \psi | \psi \rangle + \langle \phi | \phi \rangle - \langle \psi | \phi \rangle - \langle \phi | \psi \rangle
 $$

For normalized states $$(psi\| = \|\phi\| = 1)$$:
$$
 \|\psi - \phi\|^2 = 2 - 2 \text{Re}(\langle \psi | \phi \rangle)
 $$
And since $$(\psi | \phi)$$ is a complex number,
$$(\text{Re}(\langle \psi | \phi \rangle) \leq |\langle \psi | \phi \rangle|)$$:
$$
 \|\psi - \phi\|^2 = 2 - 2 |\langle \psi | \phi \rangle| = 2(1 - F(\psi, \phi))
 $$
Therefore:
$$
 d(\psi, \phi) = \sqrt{2(1 - F(\psi, \phi))}
 $$

For pure states, the distance in Hilbert space is directly related to fidelity through the formula $$(d(\psi, \phi) = \sqrt{2(1 - F(\psi, \phi))})$$.
Again, what do you think of that ?

What do you think of that? That question is too vague, and check-my-work questions are off-topic.

OK then. As for the short version ? It's basically the same question

Yes, it is. Would-you-agree = check-my-work.

But there's.no work there. I'm just asking about the connection between fidelity (as a measure of overlap between the state) and distance in Hiberr state (As a measure of dissimilarity-- at least, I think it is !)

What exactly is the question?

"Woud you say that distance in Hilbert space and fidelity are inversely related ?"

What does $|\psi-\phi\rangle$ represent? Is it a quantum state? If so, then $\langle\psi-\phi|\psi-\phi\rangle=1$.

|ψ−ϕ⟩ is not necessarily a quantum state, I would say... because it is not guaranteed to be normalized. It is simply a vector in Hilbert space that represents the difference between two quantum states.

The connection between Fidelity and the Trace distance, defined as
$$
D(\rho,\sigma) = \frac 12 \operatorname{tr}(|\rho-\sigma|)
$$
Is well known in literature. Check, for example, Nielsen, Michael A., and Isaac L. Chuang. Quantum computation and quantum information Chapter 9 section 2.3. pg 415-416. The bound you found is generalized to
$$
1-F(\rho,\sigma)\leq D(\rho,\sigma)\leq \sqrt{1-F(\rho,\sigma)^2}
$$
Which is proved first time in this article by Fuchs and van de Graaf.
There is a related question in other stack about to saturate this inequality here.

Thank you very much! I thought I saw this connection with the notion of trace, which I need to think about.
Nevertheless, is it really the same notion of distance as that implied in my question? I was talking about the Hilbert distance (sometimes called the Hilbert-Schmidt distance, I think?), defined by the norm, and not the ‘trace norm’...
